# About returning references to objects

Tags: c++

No, this isn't about the mistake everyone makes of passing locals. I'm just trying to understanding returning a reference to an object you pass in (I'm reading through primer).

So if I have a function like this:

```
const foo & foo::function2(const foo & val) const
{
    using namespace std;
    return *this;
}
```

and then I'm in main doing this:

```
foo object1;
object1.someproperty = 7;

foo object2 = object1.function2(object1);
object2.someproperty = 5;

cout << &object1 << endl;
cout << &object2 << endl;
```

When I return by reference, shouldn't object2 have the same address (and properties) as object1? Shouldn't changing "someproperty" in one object alter the value in the other? Or, does returning a reference to an object simply copy over the values into the new object?

It seems like the same thing is going on as if I just said that I was going to return a foo object instead of a reference to one.

Comment: No, because your declaring two different objects on stack and copying their values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
foo object2 = object1.function2(object1);
```

`function2()` returns a reference to `object1`; the `foo` copy constructor is then invoked to copy `object1` into `object2`, because `object2` is declared as a `foo` object.

If you declared `object2` as a const reference instead:

```
const foo& object2 = object1.function2(object1);
```

then `object2` would be a reference to `object1`.

Comment: Ah ok, makes sense that a couple things implicitly happen under the hood. Thanks everyone for the very quick and thorough responses.

Answer (score 1):

You hit the automatic copy constructor when you assigned to `object2`. Effectively what happened was:

```
foo object2(object1.function2(object1));
```

Where the automatically generated copy constructor is this:

```
class foo {
public:
  foo(const foo& other) {
    //shallow copy other to this
  }
}
```

In order to get the code to do what you think it should do, you need to declare object 2 as const reference:

```
const foo& object2 = object1.function2(object1);
//&object2 == &object1
```

Answer (score 0):

The line of code:

```
foo object2 = object1.function2(object1);
```

does 2 things.

1. a reference (which happens to refer to `object1`) is returned from `function2()`
2. the initialization of `object2` creates a copy of the object returned by `function2()`